# Serve gzip files

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have some json files that I have compressed using gzip to save space on the server.

Right now when I have to respond with the content of the file I am:

- Reading the file in memory and uncompress it.
- Parse to Json
- Send response to client with json content.

I have also enabled gzip conmpression in the server side so at the end the json that I am sending as a response is being gzip again.

Can I achieve the same without uncompressing and parsing the files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like below...try and see if this works:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("Path-to-gzip-compressed-json-file"));
response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");

return response;
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks! it really speed things up. Just one comment, if you want to update the answer, I had to first assigned the content and then add the header otherwise it throws an exception.